# Terraform: Cannot find modules moved to new state

Tags: terraform

I am moving s3 buckets between states. Specifically I am moving 2 buckets from state_a to state_b. After copying the Terraform code to state_b - on the root folder - I am running the following commands:

```sh
terraform state mv -state=terraform.tfstate -state-out=../state_b/terraform.tfstate module.bucket_a module.bucket_a
terraform state mv -state=terraform.tfstate -state-out=../state_b/terraform.tfstate module.bucket_b module.bucket_b
```

I am running these commands under the state_a folder. The output of both is

```sh
Move "module.bucket_a" to "module.bucket_a"
Successfully moved 1 object(s).
```

and the same for bucket b

Then I remove the code for these buckets from state_a and run a `terraform plan` under state_a. Everything looks good:

```sh
Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Then I run `terraform plan` under state_b. I would expect to see the same result - 0 to add, 0 to change and 0 to destroy. Unfortunately, I am seeing the following result:

```sh
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

# module.bucket_a.aws_s3_bucket.retention_bucket[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "retention_bucket" {
  ....

# module.bucket_b.aws_s3_bucket.retention_bucket[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "retention_bucket" {
  ....
```

So it seems like the move was not successful. I am trying to `terraform state list` under state_b to see all the modules in hope that I moved them under a different address but I cannot find anything under `bucket_a` or `bucket_b` name.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you add the bucket definitions to state_b `.tf` files? In your description I only see you remove the code from a: "I remove the code for these buckets from state_a".

Comment: If so, are they defined in modules `bucket_a` and `bucket_b` respectively? Does the definition in `state_b` also use `count=`? Does the other state follow the same structure?

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzOledzki for your response. In the first sentence of the description "After copying the Terraform code to state_b - on the root folder - I am running the following commands:"

Comment: I copied the exact definition from the root folder of `state_a` ot the root folder of `state_b`. So all the config properties remain the same.

Comment: Are you using `local` backend? The help text for `terraform state mv` says "-state, state-out, and -backup are legacy options supported for the local backend only. For more information, see the local backend's documentation." (TF 1.1.0)